# can't seem to update mongohq database when running app server from heroku, Invalid BSONObj spec size: 1963524096 error

Tags: mongodb, node.js, heroku, coffeescript, mongoose

I'm having a mysterious bug where a rest call that I've created on my node server updates data when run from my local app server, but will not update data when running on heroku.  In both cases, the app is calling the same database server hosted on mongohq. The only difference is where the app server code is running.  I'm stumped.  The method gets all right parameters but throw an invalid BSONObj spec size error when running on Heroku.  This works perfectly when I run the same code on my localhost app server (the database is still on mongo hq, not local).  I've tried running a find query with the same parameters and that seems to be fine in heroku, returning find results.  It's just when this update request is sent from heroku that causes problems.  Any ideas on what I can do to further debug?  I'm using coffee-script, mongoose, express and mongodb.

```
app.get '/commentTest', (req, res) ->
        postId = new BSON.ObjectID("4e9ef762ec8f890100000fb1")
        comment = new Object()
        comment.uname = "erin"
        comment.msg = "Machine generated comments 6:37pm"
        comment.date = "Wed Nov 02 2011 22:05:22 GMT+0000 (UTC)"

        console.log "updating " +  comment.msg

        Post.collection.update {_id:postId}, { $push: { comments : comment } }, (err,results) ->
            if not err
                console.log "finished updating comment" + results
                res.send 200, results
            else
                console.log "error getting post id" + postId
                res.send err
```

Here is the error

```
{"stack":"Error: Invalid BSONObj spec size: 1963524096 (00000975) first element:dated_at: 
?type=112 
at [object Object].<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection.js:404:18)
at [object Object].emit (events.js:67:17)\n    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connections/server.js:97:12)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:64:17)\n    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection.js:161:16)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:64:17)\n    at Socket._onReadable (net.js:676:14)
    at IOWatcher.onReadable [as callback] (net.js:177:10)","message":"Invalid BSONObj spec size: 1963524096 (00000975) first element:dated_at: ?type=112 "}
```

my package.json dependencies

```
  , "dependencies": {
      "express": "2.4.3"
    , "jade": ">= 0.0.1"
    , "mongodb": "0.9.6-7"
    , "colors": "0.5.0"
    , "mongoose": ">= 2.0.4"
    , "facebook-client": "1.3.0"
    , "async": ">= 0.1.12"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the 3rd comment of Post.collection.update, add {safe:true}, which should be set if you have  a callback.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  I added the safe param and got the following  "Error: Invalid BSONObj spec size: 1963524096 (00000975) first element:dated_at: ?type=112

Answer (score 0):

ok, found the problem.

I had a dependency on both mongo and mongoose and they were causing some problems since the npm install of mongo on heroku was not the same as my local build.  I removed the mongo dependency and let mongoose handle the mongo dependency, and updated the syntax to the latest mongoose version and it worked.

```
Post.collection.update
```

was changed to

```
Post.update
```